# I want to zip download all files under the specified directory

Tags: php, zip

**Code that works as I expected.**
I can zip download all files under the current directory.

```
$zipname = 'result.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if($entry != "." && $entry != ".."){
            $zip->addFile($entry);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='result.zip'");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
header("Location: result.zip");
```

---

**Code that doesn't work as expected.**
I can't zip all files under the hoge directory

```
$zipname = 'result.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($handle = opendir('./hoge')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if($entry != "." && $entry != ".."){
            $zip->addFile($entry);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='result.zip'");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
header("Location: result.zip");
```

Comment: What doesn't work in the 'hoge' version? Does it not find any files, or possibly throw an error?

Comment: No error is displayed and the browser screen display is “Page not found”. The cause of the error is that a zip file is not created. Why isn't it created?